# Slide Up and Fade Div continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

i want to make something like this https://muzzleapp.com/. I want the moving item in right part should be slide up and fade from bottom to top. Items should be moving continuously, so after the last div, it will start from beginning again. I have tried my own code. But stuck on starting from beginning point. It doesn't start properly from beginning.

**html**

```js
function moveItems(el) {
  var x = 1;
  var flag = 0;
  var elems = $(el).nextAll();
  count = elems.length;
  elems.each (function (i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (x>1) { 
        y = x-1;
        $('#slider_'+y).show().delay(2000).slideUp().fadeOut();
      }       
      $('#slider_'+x).show().delay(2000).slideUp();
      x++;
      if (!--count) {
        setTimeout(function() {
        moveItems('.panel');
        }, 6000)
      }
    }, i*2000);
  })
}

moveItems('.panel');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id='slider_1'>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        slider 1
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel" id='slider_2'>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        slider 2
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel" id='slider_3'>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        slider 3
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML and a code snippet of what you tried

Comment: @AravindS i have updated with html. kindly check

Comment: Define *«start properly»*....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your logic a little to handle the hide and show. Here is the updated preview https://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/hd465gpc/13/

```js
function moveItems(el) {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(el);
  Array.from(elems).forEach((item,index) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
     index+=1;
     $('#slider_'+index).show().delay(2000).slideUp().fadeOut();
     if (index == elems.length) {
       setTimeout(function() {
     for(j=1;j<= elems.length;j++){ $('#slider_'+j).show()}
           moveItems('.panel');
        }, 6000)
      }
      
    }, index*2000);
})
}

moveItems('.panel');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id='slider_1'>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        slider 1
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel" id='slider_2'>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        slider 2
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel" id='slider_3'>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        slider 3
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel" id='slider_4'>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        slider 4
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel" id='slider_5'>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            slider 5
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Aravind S almost working. Just the last item comes a bit late from the second time the function executes. it works perfectly first time the function executes. do you have any idea?

Comment: just the last item comes a bit late from the second time the function executes: Are you referring the delay in showing all slider once everything removed?

Comment: no. the delay is ok after all removed though i dont want the removal. i want insert the first one at the bottom after the last item. but here the concern is when the function executes second time the last item doesnt slide up from bottom instead it appears suddenly on the screen.

Comment: Apologies.. I couldn't understand it."but here the concern is when the function executes second time the last item doesn't slide up from bottom instead it appears suddenly on the screen" - it looks like slide only for me

Comment: pls kindly look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qmgkm5Y_nIfsluApYzjJCxEbwmy5jS3B/view

you can see the card of 'ben'  slideup after 'steven' when first the fucntion call. But in second time it doesnt slide up instead appears suddenly.

Comment: How may slides you have? seen the video...will check and revert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176851/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-wahidsherief).

Comment: @WahidSherief Happy to help!